# How to animate an SVG's paths fill-opacity property?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, svg

I have the following Gauge component:

[image: Guage Compoment]

The component is also rendering here: https://codesandbox.io/s/react-example-e3nxg

The component takes the prop `rating` as a number.

What I'd love to learn how to do is animate the path's opacity values. For example, if the prop for rating is passed a value of `5`... How to make it so the component animates in each path, one at a time on a set time-delay between each path.

Any ideas on how this could be done?

Comment: with the SMIL animate tag perhaps

Comment: Chrome 45 deprecated SMIL in favor of CSS animations and Web animations

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/react-example-1trl5
can you chekc this, this may help you, or may be this is what you are looking into

Comment: @AnApprentice and then they rescinded that deprecation.

Comment: @AkhilAravind thanks but our goal is to heave each path animated in individually one, and then another, and then another until complete. The code shared animates all the paths in at the same time.

Comment: @AnApprentice I have made a little update, could you check the sandbox now.
https://codesandbox.io/s/react-example-1trl5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please checkout the  sandbox url
[Sandbox link](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-example-1trl5)

I made a little change in the css

```
  #gauge {
  fill: red;
}

.Animate-Draw {
  fill-opacity: 0;
  animation-timing-function: ease-in;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  animation-name: FillIn;
  animation-duration: 4s 0.5s;
  /* animation-delay: .5s; */
}
.Animate-Draw:nth-child(1) {
  animation-delay: 0.5s;
}
.Animate-Draw:nth-child(2) {
  animation-delay: 1s;
}
.Animate-Draw:nth-child(3) {
  animation-delay: 1.5s;
}
.Animate-Draw:nth-child(4) {
  animation-delay: 2s;
}
.Animate-Draw:nth-child(5) {
  animation-delay: 2.5s;
}
.Animate-Draw:nth-child(6) {
  animation-delay: 3s;
}
.Animate-Draw:nth-child(7) {
  animation-delay: 3.5s;
}
.Animate-Draw:nth-child(8) {
  animation-delay: 4s;
}

@keyframes FillIn {
  from {
    fill-opacity: 0;
  }
  to {
    fill-opacity: 1;
  }
}
```

I hope this is what you are looking for.

Comment: Thanks for sharing this - this is interesting but the problem here is that all the paths should always be showing, we have want to animate in is the opacity property.

Comment: Idea being, when the UIC first loads, all the paths are showing with an opacity of .2.. And then if the rating is 2, the first 3 items (0,1,2) animate in, one at a time to a full opacity. Is that possible with your solution?

Comment: let me try, looks like css animation with svg is much challenging